# FMDB check if empty method and move forward separation

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

In FMDB the `next` function (as in `if a!.next {}`) does both checking if there is another row and also moving forward if there is another row, can we do these things separately, like only check if there is another row?

I have read the documentation but there seems no such direct method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`next`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMResultSet.html#//api/name/next) method in FMDB is simply a wrapper around the [`sqlite3_step`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) function. You may be used to separate functions for "advance the recordset's cursor" and the "EOF test" that you see in other environments, but this is just how SQLite does it.

So, unfortunately, no, SQLite doesn't really have separate functions for "is there another row" and "retrieve the next row". It's one function, [`sqlite3_step`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), which is called by FMDB's [`next`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMResultSet.html#//api/name/next), that serves both purposes. See the [SQLite C interface API](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html) for a complete list of the SQLite functions.

Perhaps FMDB's use of a class called `FMRecordSet` invites this sort of confusion, but we have to remember that it's really just a thin wrapper for the SQLite C API. It is limited to the same functions inherent in that API.

Comment: Is there somesort of 'cursor' as in android here? I really could not find it, please direct me if you know something on this, its very important in my current project as i am converting a android app to ios and it would increase a lot of complexity if i dont find a workaround,thanks!

Comment: I understand what you're looking for (tho, I admit I was guessing you were coming from a Microsoft ADO/DAO world, because that's how they do it there, too), but that's not part of the standard SQLite API, and thus not part of the FMDB's thin wrapper around the SQLite API.

Comment: I know this is how you may be used to iterating through record sets, but in all fairness, the SQLite approach works perfectly well, too. It's just a slightly different way of tackling the same problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply, i guess querying multiple times and iterating is the only way out.

Comment: If you step back and update your question with a description of your broader logic, we might be able to just different patterns that accomplish the same thing using the API the way that SQLite structures it. Don't get me wrong: I'm with you, that I'm more accustomed to having separate calls, but the SQLite structure has never forced me to perform queries multiple times, just because `sqlite3_step` both retrieves the record set and tests for "no more records" in one call.

Comment: Ok I read some documentation and restructured some code, it is better now, i was getting confused by 'hasAnotherRow' function. Thanks for all the help, it got solved now, no repeated queries but just a while loop at places like 'cursor.movetolast' but thats ok.